# Loading an XML file from a string in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I'm trying to load a DOM using `simplexml_load_string` in PHP, but program always terminates right where the call is (nothing after the call gets executed). I've loaded the xml from a file into a string using.

```
$source = file_get_contents("/path/to/file.xml");
```

Now, calling `echo $source;` returns the full output of the xml file in my browser. This is the source I get in browser:

```
<xml>
<title>Title</title>
<date>4 April 2015</date>
<content> 
    //...HTML content...//
</content>
</xml>
```

However, when the program calls

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
```

the program terminates and anything after that statement doesn't run. I've been through the docs and searched for hours now and can't seem to find anything like this. Before trying this method to construct the DOM I tried using `simplexml_load_file` with identical results.
*Has anyone seen something like this?*

Comment: any errors? Do you have error_reporting enabled, have you checked logs, ... ? Anyway trying to parse HTML content by xml parser might be a bit problematic since xml is much more strict than html.

Comment: @hynner Ah I see, I just enabled error reporting and got "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: simplexml_load_string()..." but I thought simplexml came installed in the php core?

Comment: it can be disabled see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php)

Comment: It must be something with your server configuration.  I just tried a simple example, and it worked for me, even with the `xml` root tags.

Comment: Yep, it was a server configuration issue. My university servers are outrageously still pre-PHP5. Installed the simplexml backport available at http://www.ister.org/code/simplexml44/doc.html and it works fine. Thanks all.

Comment: oh please give the name of that university.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML string is not valid XML. You cannot have an element name that is called "xml" or an element that name starts with "xml". Try renaming your root element i.e. use something like `<root>` instead of `<xml>`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps, I just tried to reproduce your issue, but it worked fine for me.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xml>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</xml>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents("./file2.xml");

echo $source;

echo "after source \n";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);

print_r($xml);

echo "after xml";

?>
```

Output:

> Joe Jane I know that's the answer -- but what's the question? after
>   source SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Forty What? [from] => Joe
>   [to] => Jane [body] => I know that's the answer -- but what's the
>   question? ) after xml